# Seperating tuples in list in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples

I want to seperate tuples in list that comes from a sqlite database. But I don't know why I can't seperate them anyway.

Here is the output : [('3:45',), ('4:52',), ('5:42',), ('6:52',)]

I'm pulling that output from sqlite database like this :

```
asking = "Select SongTimes from Song_List"
self.cursor.execute(asking)
times = list(self.cursor.fetchall())
print(times)
```

And after that I want to sum all of song times in that list. But I need to acquire them "3:45" like this. After I will seperate them 3,45 like this and the rest is kinda easy. But like I said I need to focus that output for seperating these tuples. That "," is troublemaker I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sum the times", but basically the comma is just part of the output display. These are all single element tuples, so `times[i][0]` is all you need to "separate" a tuple (more accurately, access the first and only element of a tuple). If you want the output flattened into a 1-d list, use `[x[0] for x in times]`. Please post your expected output. Thanks.

Comment: `[ i[0] for i in output_list ]` would give you a list of first elements from the tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
times = [('3:45',), ('4:52',), ('5:42',), ('6:52',)]
seconds = 0  # Total number of seconds

# Iterate over all the tuples
for time in times:
    time = time[0]  # Get first element of tuple
    m, s = time.split(":")  # split string in two removing ':'

    seconds += 60 * int(m) + int(s)  # Convert str to int and add to total sum

print(seconds)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise @Louis Lac. I notest there is just a little bit problem at your code. I need to change  " m, s = time[0].split(":")  " that part to " m,s = time.split(":") " But with you I solved the problem. Thank you again. I couldn't tag your name btw.

Comment: Nice to hear that it works! It’s juste à error on m’y side, I’ll correct my answer